# Unable to Create SKU attribute as a Promotion Condition

Tags: promotions

I am trying to create a promotional rule "20% OFF for specific SKU" on Magento 1.9.0.1, however I did not see the SKU attribute in the "Shopping Cart Price Rules". Is that something that I missed out?

[image: condition]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes > SKU

Change "Use for Promo Rule Conditions" to "Yes"

You should then have this available to use in the Promotions.

Answer (score -1):

You need to edit the sku attribute and set it to be used in promotions.